# I don't quite understand the while loop in python

Tags: python, while-loop

```
def AddSingleCard(self):
   symbols = ['heart', 'diamond', 'club', 'spade']
   #newCardSign = ''
   newCardNumber, newCardSign = raw_input().split()
   try:
       newCardNumber = int(float(newCardNumber))
   except:
       newCardNumber, newCardSign = raw_input().split()
   while (newCardNumber not in (2,15) or newCardSign not in symbols):
      newCardNumber, newCardSign = raw_input().split()
   newCard = [newCardNumber, newCardSign]
```

I'm trying to loop until the input will be a number between 2-15, and the string will be one of the symbols, but the while loop works for me only if the wrong input is the numbers, if the numbers are in range and the string is not, the program just gets stuck in the while line, and waits for next input, instead of going down to the next line and get the input to the right place...
I believe it's connected to the syntax of my while loop, but I can't put my finger on the problem. 
(my programming background is c, I'm new to python)

tnx!

Comment: `not in (2, 15)` is only testing for 2 numbers, not for the range.

Comment: `newCardNumber` will be a string after `raw_input().split()`. You are not converting it to `int` in the loop.

Comment: acctualy it's works for me, any other number then 2-15 start the loop again. can you tell me why? and if i change it to 
 while (newCardNumber not in range(2,15) or newCardSign not in symbols): it do the oposite

Comment: i know jusper, i'll do that after, still trying to understand the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def AddSingleCard():
    symbols = ['heart', 'diamond', 'club', 'spade']
    newCardNumber = newCardSign = None
    while (newCardNumber not in range(2, 16) or newCardSign not in symbols):
        newCardNumber, newCardSign = raw_input('Enter Number and Symbol with space between:').split()
        try:
            newCardNumber = int(newCardNumber)
        except:
            continue
    newCard = [newCardNumber, newCardSign]
    return newCard


AddSingleCard()
```

1. Convert `newCardNumber` to `int`
2. change (2,15) to range(2,16)

Comment: The only right way to do this is to use a `while True` loop.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: take my word back. work's. i get it now that if i tried it twice, the second time loop tried to check if the newCardNumber is int, and coulden't becuse i didn't convert it. thank you!

Comment: @kia because that's how you do a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_while_loop in Python, and the problem here asks for this kind of loop (body executed at least once). Also, a blank `except: continue` is bad style.

Comment: @Jasper I know what you mean. But in your answer, din't you user both `if` and `except: continue`?

Comment: I used `except ValueError` and printed a meaningful error message. The `if` is used to leave the loop if everyting is all right.

Answer (score 1):

If you know C, you might want to use a `do ... while` loop, because the loop body must be executed at least once. But there is no such thing as a `do ... while` loop in Python. You have to start with `while True:` and `break` out of the loop if your condition is met.

```
def AddSingleCard(self):
   symbols = ['heart', 'diamond', 'club', 'spade']

   while True: 
       newCardNumber, newCardSign = raw_input("Enter card number and sign (heart, diamond, club, spade), seperated by space").split()
       try:
           newCardNumber = int(newCardNumber)
       except ValueError:
           print "Card number must be a number between 2 and 15"
           continue

       if newCardNumber in range(2,16) and newCardSign in symbols:
              break

       print "Card number or symbol not valid"

   newCard = [newCardNumber, newCardSign]
```