# Why does my python loop continually hit my exception clause?

Tags: python

```
classname = ""
classpick = input("Enter class name (\"A,B,C\") ")
while classname == "":
    try:
        if classpick.upper() == "A":
            classname = "classA.txt"
        elif classpick.upper() == "B":
            classname = "classB.txt"
        elif classpick.upper() == "C":
            classname = "classC.txt"
        elif classpick.upper() not in ["A","B","C"]:
            raise ValueError
        else:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid value. Please enter a letter A,B or C.")
```

Is this code right? For some reason if an invalid input is entered the code just keeps looping the except clause. Any ideas why?

Comment: You might also check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/34617551/3456281, this way you don't have to initialize `classname` to empty string first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the code to ask for the input again... try this:

```
classname = ""
classpick = input("Enter class name (\"A,B,C\") ")
while classname == "":
    try:
        if classpick.upper() == "A":
            classname = "classA.txt"
        elif classpick.upper() == "B":
            classname = "classB.txt"
        elif classpick.upper() == "C":
            classname = "classC.txt"
        elif classpick.upper() not in ["A","B","C"]:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid value. Please enter a letter A,B or C.")
        classpick = input("Enter class name (\"A,B,C\") ")
```

EDIT:

> What is the last elif good for? – Jasper

Nothing! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try again with bad input in except it will break, you could make function and return in except.

Comment: No problem @DanielRhodes . However, you may want to think about consulting the python docs before asking simple questions such as this one or even check other stackoverflow posts please.

Comment: @RedIcon ermmmm... no it doesn't...
D3107 I'll keep that in mind - this is my first post; sorry!

Comment: @Jasper Good point... it seems redundant but I left it in just incase it had some purpose. Code works fine without it

Comment: @RedIcon What sort of error are you getting? Works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

You've also got a redundant elif/else statement.

```
classname = ""
while classname == "":
    classpick = input("Enter class name (\"A,B,C\") ")
    try:
        if classpick.upper() == "A":
            classname = "classA.txt"
        elif classpick.upper() == "B":
            classname = "classB.txt"
        elif classpick.upper() == "C":
            classname = "classC.txt"
        #elif classpick.upper() not in ["A","B","C"]:
            #raise ValueError  This and the else below it are redundant.
        else:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid value. Please enter a letter A,B or C.")
```

A cleaner solution might be:

```
classname = ""

while classname == "":
    classpick = input("Enter class name (\"A,B,C\") ")
    try:
        if classpick.upper() in ["A","B","C"]:
            classname = "class"+classpick.upper()+".txt"
        else:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid value. Please enter a letter A,B or C.")
```

Comment: you can remove while loop too :)

Comment: Can you? I think that would make you only have one chance to enter a name

Comment: @D3107 solution doesn't break after bad inputs twice in a row but I appreciate this more efficient alternative

Comment: Ah, sorry I see that now

Comment: @OwenHempel Nice efficiency but why is my solution breaking after 2 bad inputs for you? I'm not experiencing the same issue.

Comment: check out my solution @D3107

Comment: @D3107 It wasn't breaking, that was my own fault. Trying to get a strikethrough on that